# Mocking laravel DB facades when method using mockery/mockery

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, query-builder, mockery

I am using mockery/mockery to mock laravel db facade on my unit test. But I don't know how to create a stub for the when method. So here is my class that I want to test.

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class TestRepo
{
    public function testQb()
    {
        DB::table('users')
            ->when(true, function($query) {
                $query->where('email_verified_at', null);
            })
            ->get();
    }
}
```

and I want to make sure that the querybuilder runs the `when` method including the clousure.

so far I have this test without the stub for `when` method

```php
public function test_example()
{
    DB::shouldReceive('table')->once()->with('users')->andReturnSelf();
    DB::shouldReceive('get')->once()->andReturn(collect(new User()));
    (new TestRepo())->testQb();
    $this->assertTrue(true);
}
```

this will test will fail because I dont have a stub for laravel db facade `when` method.

can somebody tells me how can I achieve this? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Mockery can mock methods chains, as described [here](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/demeter_chains.html).

```
DB::shouldReceive('table->when->get')->andReturn(collect(new User()));
```

But as this has less assertions by avoiding `with()`, i would suggest asserting the return data.

Comment: thank you of this idea. but It didn't on my end. I got this error. may I did it wrong

https://pastebin.com/zurAS9KH

Comment: This seems like to be an error related to wrong phpunit version compared to the php version running it

Comment: yes your right. my phpstorm is running php8 and i got phpunit 9.5 but i run it using php7.4.. i still got an error. https://pastebin.com/0uNngrJH

Comment: It doesnt find any testcase what is your class names like and whicj testcase does they extend?

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to do that, you are literally testing the Facade not your logic/flow. You must never test `core` code as that is already tested.

The way of testing that code is to do a Feature or Unit Test for each case:

1. Get all `users` (even `users` with `email_verified_at`).
2. Get all `users` that have `email_verified_at` as `null`.

In both cases, you have to have `users` with both conditions, and only the first condition will return all `users`, but the second one should not return a user were `email_verified_at` is not `null`.

---

Your query can be upgraded:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

User::when(true, function (Builder $query) {
    return $query->whereNull('email_verified_at');
})
    ->get();
```